# Check column and if condition is True send an email

Tags: vba, for-loop, worksheet-function

In the code below I need to check two columns. Column "N" and "O". If I enter an "X" in column O2:O801 I check to make sure there is not an "X" in column N2:N801, if there is I exit the the sub, If column "N" has no "X" and I enter an "X" in column "O" (which is the column I will be changing when I need to send an email), then I send an email. I'm using "For.. Next" to go down my columns. The problem is that the code sends an email no matter what is in column "N". This occurs after I enter and "X" in column "O". How can I solve this?

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

'This code checks for car not returned and call the email sub
Dim T As Integer
    
For T = 2 To 801
      
        If Worksheets("April").Range("K" & T).Value <> "X" And Worksheets("April").Range("O" & T).Value = "X" Then
                    
            Call Email
           
        'End If
      
        On Error Resume Next

    Next T
        
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

`On error resume next` is really not your friend in VBA programming. Try this one, my understanding is that whenever there are two `X` on a given row an action is triggered:

```
Sub TestMe()

    Dim t As Long
    
    For t = 2 To 801
        With Worksheets(1)
            If (UCase(.Range("K" & t).Value) = "X") And (UCase(.Range("O" & t).Value) = "X") Then
                Debug.Print "Email sent for "; t
            End If
        End With
    Next t
        
End Sub
```

Probably not following 100% of the requirements, but with a pair of additional conditions you may be there. Added `Ucase()` to make sure that "x" is also included.

Comment: Hi. What I need is for the event to trigger when cell "K" <> "X" and cell "O" = "X". So, far this did not work.